# PHP PDO how to search for 2 or more values in a query?

Tags: php, search, pdo

Let's say I have a search form, and I want to search by name or email, I only manage to search by one value, otherwise, I get an SQL error.

I looked through the site but didn't find the solution for my problem.

This code works:

```
    if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $search = $_POST['search'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` LIKE ?";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->execute(array($search));
```

End when i try it like this it does not:

```
    if (isset($_POST['search'])) {

    $search = $_POST['search'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` LIKE ? OR `email` LIKE ?";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->execute(array($search));
```

How can I search it by both name or email?

EDIT: 
Here is the error:

Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

EDIT2:

Here is the solution that works:

```
    $search = $_POST['search'];

    if (isset($search)) {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` LIKE ? OR `email` LIKE 
    ?";

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->execute(["%$search%", "%$search%"]);
    }
```

Comment: What is var_dump of $search?

Comment: string(9) "something"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that `$search` variable contains only one element. Try this:

```
$search = $_POST['search'];

if (isset($search)) {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` LIKE ? OR `email` LIKE ?";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->execute([$search, $search]);
}
```

---

Another solution would be to set the `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` connection option to `TRUE`. This way you can use multiple *named markers* with the same name (here `:search`) and assign them the value of a single variable (here the composed string `'%' . $search . '%'`).

As a note: When one or two percent characters (`%`) are used, the query will return all values *containing* the provided search value. Whereas, in the case of completely omitted `%`-characters, the query will return all *exact* values, and `LIKE` can be replaced with `=`. It's up to you which alternative you want to use.

Here is a complete example:

**connection.php:**

```
<?php

/*
 * This page contains the code for creating a PDO connection instance.
 */

// Db configs.
define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('PORT', 3306);
define('DATABASE', 'tests');
define('USERNAME', 'abc');
define('PASSWORD', 'def');
define('CHARSET', 'utf8');

// Error reporting.
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); /* SET IT TO 0 ON A LIVE SERVER! */

// Create a PDO instance as db connection to db.
$connection = new PDO(
        sprintf('mysql:host=%s;port=%s;dbname=%s;charset=%s', HOST, PORT, DATABASE, CHARSET)
        , USERNAME
        , PASSWORD
        , [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => TRUE, /* This is the option of interest */
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => FALSE,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        ]
);
```

**test.php:**

```
<?php

require 'connection.php';

// Hardcoded value, for testing. Should be read from $_POST array.
$search = 'joe';

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE :search OR email LIKE :search';

$bindings = [
    ':search' => '%' . $search . '%',
];

$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute($bindings);

$fetchedData = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Display fetched data.
if ($fetchedData) {
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($fetchedData, TRUE) . '</pre>';
} else {
    echo 'No data found.';
}
```

**Results:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => j.r.
            [email] => joey@example.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => joe
            [email] => joe@example.com
        )

)
```

**Table definition:**

```
CREATE TABLE tests.users (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(100) NULL,
    email varchar(100) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT users_PK PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

**Used data:**

```
id|name   |email              |
--|-------|-------------------|
 1|j.r.   |joey@example.com   |
 2|michael|michael@example.com|
 3|joe    |joe@example.com    |
```

**Resources:**

- [Emulation mode. PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#emulation)
- [PDO::__construct](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)
- [PDO::setAttribute](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php)
- [Predefined Constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php)

Comment: I think i cant do that because i have only one $_POST field in my search form?
And i want typed string to match LIKE either name or email but in one field.

Comment: Show me real world sql query you want to execute

Comment: $search variable must be array with two values otherwise your code prone to sql injections.

Comment: i want to execute this:
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` LIKE ? OR `email` LIKE ?";

Comment: For example if your `$search` variable is` "joe joe@gmail.com"`, and you need user with name joe or email joe@gmail.com you can split $search variable to array by space as delimeter `explode(' ', $search)` and then execute query

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE ? OR email LIKE ?"`
It's not a sql query, show me query with values.
Show me real world example. What is $search value and what $sql query you want execute for the $search variable

Comment: lets say i type '.net' or just 'a', i want all the users with either name OR email containing that string to be shown, i hope you can understand what i mean.

Comment: Tnx. And what do you suggest for $search var?
i tried  this 
$search = [$_POST['search'], $_POST['search']];
but it says array to string conversion

Comment: thank you mate, now it works. Ill update my post so it might help someone.

Comment: @dakis It would be nice if you edit my post and add other solutions. Thanks